# How does the spell "Extract water elemental" interact with the energy substitution class feature of elemental savant?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, class-feature

Basically as the title states.

The elemental savant energy substitution states that any damaging spell of a certain type is converted to a chosen type (in my instance, fire).

Will this spell instead extract a fire elemental somehow if the creature is slain? Or will the substitution not take place since the damage of the spell deals is untyped?

Spell in question:
"Extract water elemental" Spell compendium Page 86

Prestige Class Elemental Savant -> 3.5 Complete Arcane page 32-34
Class feature in question: Elemental specialty

What is the correct interaction between the spell and the mentioned class ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elemental savant’s elemental specialty:

> When the savant casts a spell that normally deals energy damage,

*Extract water elemental*:

> This deals 1d6 points of damage per caster level (maximum 20d6), or half damage on a successful Fortitude save.

As *extract water elemental*’s damage is untyped, it is not energy damage, so elemental specialty’s “When...” condition is not met, so it does not trigger, and it has no effect on the spell.

Also, for the record, *Sandstorm* defines “desiccation damage” as a new type of damage—and explicitly says “Desiccation is not an energy type.” It would make a certain amount of sense to use desiccation damage for *extract water elemental*, though note this would have some balance implications (desiccation automatically causes fatigue—probably OK for a single-target 6th-level spell, though).